# the colour disappeared after split view

Tags: rendering, materials, 3d-view, lighting, color

i was working on the donut tutorial in the part of material and lighting in "split view" and after i closed one screen the colour disappeared and i had left with just the black and white screen.
[image]
when i render in f12 i could see the colour again. i tried to enter the saved files and they appear also without colour.[image]

Comment: Looks like you are in Solid mode (small spheres on the right corner) press Z and select render or material preview to see them again

Answer (score 1):

[image]

select the circles on the top to alter between the two modes(solid mode and viewport shading)

Comment: thank you so much! i feel so dumb

Comment: your welcome! and BTW you are not dumb you`re just a beginner